# わけ accompanied by な particle

Tags: grammar, particles, copula, particle-な

What exactly does な particle mean when used with わけ?
Example (pulled from Google):

> あいつが犯人**なわけ**がないじゃないか.

I know exactly what this sentence means, but I'm just a little unsure on what the な is doing there? I couldn't find a suitable answer in my dictionary, the only thing I can thing of is it being another form of だ.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You're right, this is a form of だ.  You're probably used to seeing な following *na*-adjectives.  It can be considered the form of だ that appears before nouns:

> キレイだ 　　　←　　Here, だ ends a clause.
>   キレイな花　 　←　　Here, だ changes to な before the noun 花.

But when だ follows a regular noun, it typically doesn't take the な form.  The main exception is when it comes before certain noun-like things including わけ and の:

> リンゴだ　　　←　　Here, だ ends a clause.
>   リンゴなの　　←　　Here, だ changes to な before the nominalizer の.

The same thing happens in your sentence:

> あいつが犯人だ　　　　←　　Here, だ ends a clause.
>   あいつが犯人なわけ　　←　　Here, だ changes to な before the formal noun わけ.

It changes form to な.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's nice to have my thoughts on it being a form of だ confirmed. 

Just one point though, snailboat. You say that the な in na-adjectives is also a form of だ, but the textbook I used to use said that the な state of being and the な in na-adjectives have nothing to do with each other.

Does that mean my text book was wrong? It is a very popular textbook too (called "Japanese the manga way")

Comment: Historically they're the exact same だ, although you can treat them as separate things if you like as a matter of theory.